# Facebook mutual friends between me and facebook page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

i need to get mutual friends between logged user and facebook page by id.

I can get mutual friend between two users like this :

me/mutualfriends/{userId}

i tested it in Graph API Explorer and works well.

But it`s not work with {pageId} ..

In Facebook documentation : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user
they said : /mutualfriends - The mutual friends between two people.

Ok.. Obviously this is my problem.. but what is the solution ?

What i need to use to get mutual friends between user and page

Comment: A page doesn't have friends, therefore there can't be "mutual friends" between a person and a page.

Comment: Ok,that sounds write. So i need ,friends list that like a page ? How can i get this ?

Comment: Why don't you post your solution as an answer?

Comment: Because i need to wait 8 hours after i created my question. I`m new user .. Sorry .. I`ll add it tomorrow

Answer (score 2):

Ok i found a solutin that works for me.. :

SELECT uid, username FROM user WHERE uid in (SELECT uid FROM page_fan WHERE page_id = {pageID} AND uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=me()))

This fql query return this what i need..

Thanks for help